# Order of callbacks when changing state in "on_enter" callback

Tags: python, transition

I use the state machine python implementation **transitions**.

When I try to change the state of the machine directly in a **on_enter** callback, the order of callback calls is not the one I expect.

Please find below the minimal runnable code where the issue happens:

```
# coding: utf8

"""Minimal script."""

from transitions.extensions import GraphMachine as Machine

class MyStateMachine(object):
    """My state machine"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialization."""
        super(MyStateMachine, self).__init__()

        states = ["state_a", "state_b"]
        transitions = [
            {
                "trigger": "go_b",
                "source": "state_a",
                "dest": "state_b",
                "before": "before",
                "after": "after",
            },
            {
                "trigger": "go_a",
                "source": "state_b",
                "dest": "state_a",
                "before": "before",
                "after": "after",
            },
        ]

        self.__machine = Machine(self, states=states, transitions=transitions,
                                 initial="state_a")

    def before(self):
        """Before transition."""
        print "before transition"

    def after(self):
        """After transition."""
        print "after transition - current state:", self.state

    def on_enter_state_a(self):
        """When entering in state A."""
        print "enter state A"

    def on_exit_state_a(self):
        """When exiting state A."""
        print "exit state A"

    def on_enter_state_b(self):
        """When entering in state A."""
        print "enter state B"
        self.go_a()

    def on_exit_state_b(self):
        """When exiting state A."""
        print "exit state B"


def main():
    """Main function."""
    machine = MyStateMachine()
    machine.go_b()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Expected output:

```
before transition
exit state A
enter state B
after transition - current state: state_b
before transition
exit state B
enter state A
after transition - current state:  state_a
```

Observed output:

```
before transition
exit state A
enter state B
before transition
exit state B
enter state A
after transition - current state:  state_a
after transition - current state:  state_a
```

Could be that considered as a bug ?
If no, how could I get the *expected* output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer: Set Machine keyword `queued` to `True`**

From the transitions [Readme](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions#queued-transitions):

> The default behaviour in Transitions is to process events instantly. This means events within an on_enter method will be processed before callbacks bound to after are called [...] If queued processing is enabled, a transition will be finished before the next transition is triggered: machine = Machine(states=states, queued=True) [...]

What you need is to initialise `Machine` with `queued=True`. The above mentioned section covers execution orders of callbacks in both scenarios and also changes in `Machine`'s behaviour when queueing is enabled.
I added `queued` as a keyword to your presented example to illustrate the procedure:

```
from transitions.extensions import GraphMachine as Machine


class MyStateMachine(object):
    """My state machine"""
    # added 'queued' to constructor of custom class...
    def __init__(self, queued=False):
        """Initialization."""
        super(MyStateMachine, self).__init__()

        states = ["state_a", "state_b"]
        transitions = [
            {
                "trigger": "go_b",
                "source": "state_a",
                "dest": "state_b",
                "before": "before",
                "after": "after",
            },
            {
                "trigger": "go_a",
                "source": "state_b",
                "dest": "state_a",
                "before": "before",
                "after": "after",
            },
        ]
        # ... to pass the value to 'Machine'
        self.__machine = Machine(self, states=states, transitions=transitions,
                                 initial="state_a", queued=queued)

    def before(self):
        print "before transition"

    def after(self):
        print "after transition - current state:", self.state

    def on_enter_state_a(self):
        print "enter state A"

    def on_exit_state_a(self):
        print "exit state A"

    def on_enter_state_b(self):
        print "enter state B"
        self.go_a()

    def on_exit_state_b(self):
        """When exiting state A."""
        print "exit state B"


def main():    
    print "---- Standard behaviour ----"

    machine = MyStateMachine()
    machine.go_b()

    print "---- Now queued ----"

    queued_machine = MyStateMachine(queued=True)
    queued_machine.go_b()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
---- Standard behaviour ----
before transition
exit state A
enter state B
before transition
exit state B
enter state A
after transition - current state: state_a
after transition - current state: state_a
---- Now queued ----
before transition
exit state A
enter state B
after transition - current state: state_b
before transition
exit state B
enter state A
after transition - current state: state_a
```

**In case you care: transitions supports `logging`**

This way you do not need to clutter your code with print statements:

```
from transitions.extensions import GraphMachine as Machine
import logging


class Model(object):

    def before(self):
        pass

    def after(self):
        pass

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

model = Model()
machine = Machine(model, states=['A', 'B'], before_state_change='before',
                  after_state_change='after', initial='A')
model.to_B()
```

Output:

```
DEBUG:transitions.core:Initiating transition from state A to state B...
DEBUG:transitions.core:Executed callback 'before' before transition.
DEBUG:transitions.core:Exiting state A. Processing callbacks...
INFO:transitions.core:Exited state A
DEBUG:transitions.core:Entering state B. Processing callbacks...
INFO:transitions.core:Entered state B
DEBUG:transitions.core:Executed callback 'after' after transition.
```